# What difference between Flink time window and slide time window?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm investigation how Apache Flink works and trying to understand time windows in Flink.

Comment: Have you read this article https://flink.apache.org/news/2015/12/04/Introducing-windows.html

Comment: Thanks, I've missed this info in documentation

Answer (score 1):

The documentation outlines this well: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html

A simple TimeWindow is actually a Tumbling(Event/Processing)TimeWindow and a Sliding(Event/Processing)TimeWindow is a sliding window.

To give specific examples from the documentation (see link for illustrations):

**Tumbling Window**

> A tumbling windows assigner assigns each element to a window of a
>   specified window size. Tumbling windows have a fixed size and do not
>   overlap. For example, if you specify a tumbling window with a size of
>   5 minutes, the current window will be evaluated and a new window will
>   be started every five minutes.

**Sliding Window**

> The sliding windows assigner assigns elements to windows of fixed
>   length. Similar to a tumbling windows assigner, the size of the
>   windows is configured by the window size parameter. An additional
>   window slide parameter controls how frequently a sliding window is
>   started. Hence, sliding windows can be overlapping if the slide is
>   smaller than the window size. In this case elements are assigned to
>   multiple windows.
>
> For example, you could have windows of size 10 minutes that slides by
>   5 minutes. With this you get every 5 minutes a window that contains
>   the events that arrived during the last 10 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for the nice comparison.